# toggling images when the radio button is checked and unchecked jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have radio buttons wrapped inside images like this

```
 <div class = " monthly-radio-div padding-lr-zero radio-inline">
  <input type="radio"  name="inv_type" id="monthly" value = "monthly" >
   <label for="monthly">
    <span class="radio">
     <img src="icons/r_dis.png">
    </span>
   </label>
 </div>

 <div class = " future-radio-div padding-lr-zero radio-inline">
  <input type="radio"  name="inv_type" id="future" value = "future" >
   <label for="future">
    <span class="radio">
     <img src="icons/r_dis.png">
    </span>
   </label>
 </div>
```

When the radio button is clicked image inside the `label` will change. I have done till this. The problem here is after clicking the radio button the image changes perfectly but doesn't go back to its default image when other radio button is clicked. By this the unchecked radio also looks like they are checked. I have two images, one represents radio checked and other for radio checked.

```
$('.monthly-radio-div input').on('change', function() {
var parentDiv=$(this).parents(".monthly-radio-div:eq(0)");
if($(this).is(":checked")){
    $(parentDiv).find("img").attr("src","https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/toggle/512/radio-on-128.png");
}
else{
$(parentDiv).find("img").attr("src","https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/toggle/512/radio-off-128.png");
}
```

});

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xxyefujd/) of the code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xxyefujd/2/ I think this is what you want

Answer (score 0):

First of all you didn't add `jQuery` into your fiddle project. Also the reference to the `img` element, to which you want to apply the `src` changes, was improper. Secondly, you didn't provide the 'other' radio button inside fiddle.

```js
$('#monthly, #future').on('change', function() {
  if ($('#monthly').is(":checked")) {
    $('.radio').find(".first").attr("src", "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/toggle/512/radio-on-128.png");
    $('.radio').find(".second").attr("src", "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/toggle/512/radio-off-128.png");
  } else {
    $('.radio').find(".first").attr("src", "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/toggle/512/radio-off-128.png");
    $('.radio').find(".second").attr("src", "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/toggle/512/radio-on-128.png");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=" monthly-radio-div padding-lr-zero radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="inv_type" id="monthly" value="monthly">
  <label for="monthly">
      <span class="radio">
         <img class='first' src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/toggle/512/radio-off-128.png">
      </span>
   </label>
</div>

<div class=" monthly-radio-div padding-lr-zero radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="inv_type" id="future" value="monthly">
  <label for="future">
      <span class="radio">
         <img class='second' src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/toggle/512/radio-off-128.png">
      </span>
   </label>
</div>
```

Comment: i added jquery to it. understand the question please.

Comment: @NaveenKumar I've understood your question correctly. But you didn't provide sufficient code. Edit your jsfiddle, provide another radio button and then I will provide you another solution.

Comment: @NaveenKumar Okey, it's fine now. Check it!

Answer (score 0):

My proposal is:

- use .closest(".monthly-radio-div") instead of .parents(".monthly-radio-div:eq(0)")
- use this.checked instead of $(this).is(":checked")
- swap images

The snippet:

```js
$('.monthly-radio-div :radio').on('change', function(e) {
    var parentDiv = $(this).closest(".monthly-radio-div");

    var currImg = parentDiv.find("img").attr("src");
    var otherImg = parentDiv.siblings(".monthly-radio-div").find("img").attr("src");

    if (currImg == otherImg) {
        otherImg = "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/toggle/512/radio-on-128.png";
    }

    parentDiv.find("img").attr("src", otherImg);
    parentDiv.siblings(".monthly-radio-div").find("img").attr("src", currImg);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class = "monthly-radio-div padding-lr-zero radio-inline">
    <input type="radio"  name="inv_type" id="monthly" value = "monthly" >
    <label for="monthly">
      <span class="radio">
         <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/toggle/512/radio-off-128.png">
      </span>
    </label>
</div>

<div class = "monthly-radio-div padding-lr-zero radio-inline">
    <input type="radio"  name="inv_type" id="future" value = "monthly" >
    <label for="future">
      <span class="radio">
         <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/toggle/512/radio-off-128.png">
      </span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: if i use checkbox , users can select multiple options right, I want them to select only one out of those two. that is why radio is used. Can you enlighten me if i am doing anything wrong here ?

Comment: no. You have used checkbox which lets me to check multiple item. I want to check only one in those two options, That is why i have used radio button

Answer (score 0):

it's not listening for the change on the radio that is not clicked, so everytime your if statement is true, 
you have to change your images back to default manually then update the image next to the radio clicked 
try : 
`if($(this).is(":checked")){
    $('.monthly-radio-div img').attr("src","https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/toggle/512/radio-off-128.png");

$(parentDiv).find("img").attr("src","https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/toggle/512/radio-on-128.png");
}`

( you can remove the `else` statement )

Answer (score 0):

However, you can do it more simply with CSS : 
`input[type="radio"] + label span img{
  background: url("https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/toggle/512/radio-off-128.png");
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label span img{
   background: url("https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/toggle/512/radio-on-128.png");
}`

( Unless you have to do it with jQuery )